# Help, my usdcs are lost in genosis safe wallet :)

Tags: usdc, zksync

My USDCs were in the Genosys safe wallet, and I connected the Genosys to Orbiter and bridged from Optimism to Zksync. But now I found out that Ginosys wallet doesn't have ZkSync network  I mean, where has my money gone now? :(
I bridged with the Ginosys Safe multi-signature wallet. And now I noticed that in the Ginosys Safe wallet, the addresses of networks like Metamask are not all the same. That is, when I connect to Zksync with the ethereum address in Ginosys Safe, there is nothing in it  txhash is:https://optimistic.etherscan.io/tx/0xc2b61585e38732df014ff1036f5bde9938dc57078a4baa6c8a9f491d54d0f980

Answer (score 0):

Out of the 3 owners, there is not funds in zksync network `0x568fda4ff42c59fd47c8f7f96a7821a20832b85e` `0x2cc2a7bb82e71f117ac388d074d399cd061d7c53` `0x0f09a1727442f3d832791545dbdc16a7dc2947f6`
During bridging in methodId you have put the to address to `0x7f5c764cbc14f9669b88837ca1490cca17c31607` and refund receiver address is `0x0`. So, I don't know exactly what type of transaction is this.

[image]